# How to make path using pandas dataframe as reference

Tags: python, pandas, directory

I plan to make hundreds of dataframe with using Excel in hundreds of folders.

Reference table:

```
        Folder                         Category           Sub Category
205     News and Media                 News and Media     News and Media
206     Vehicles - Motorcycles         Vehicles           Motorcycles
207     Vehicles - Motorsports         Vehicles           Motorsports
208     Vehicles - Other Vehicles      Vehicles           Other Vehicles
```

Code example:

```
Data_Vehicles-Motorcycles = pd.read_excel('[Folder]/TopSites-Vehicles_Motorcycles-(999)-(2022_03).xlsx','Aggregated_Data_for_Time_Period')
```

Pattern

```
Data_[Folder] = pd.read_excel('[Folder]/TopSites-[Category]_[Sub Category]-(999)-(2022_03).xlsx','Aggregated_Data_for_Time_Period')
```

**Note**

I know that the folder name is using space, but I just want to the the dataframe is saved using words in folder name, no matter the regex or cleansing

Comment: [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) Will be your friend here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a column named "Path" in your dataframe.

```
df['Path'] = df['Folder'] + '/TopSites-' + df['Category'] + '_' + df['Sub Category'] + '-(999)-(2022_03).xlsx' # Create the whole path
```

After that, you can loop through your dataframe and read each path.

```
for path in df['Path']:
    folder = path.split('/')[0] # Get the folder from the path
    Data_[folder] = pd.read_excel(path)
```

Comment: NameError, Data_ is not defined